# SFAuthorizationView authorize apps preferences without changing rights

Tags: cocoa

what if I just want to use SFAuthorizationView for "setEnabled: YES/NO" of parts of UI (let's say check boxes)? I don't want to work with rights at all. I just want to know that user has set the right password asociated with his username... That's all... Is there any way how to do that without setting things like AuthorizationFlags?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would want to set the `kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsSessionUser` for your custom right.  I don't think you can cause a prompt without authorizing rights.  See [the official Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html)
 for more detail.